# Como reescribir mi consulta utilizando sintaxis de método de LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-6

Mi consulta escrita utilizando synatxis de consulta de LINQ

```
    var TableBulto = from c in db.Clientes
    from o in c.Ordens
    from s in o.SBultos.DefaultIfEmpty()

    where o.Oc == ValorOrden && o.Carga == ValorCarga && o.ClienteID == ValorIdCliente && o.CPallet == 0
    select new
    {
        c.Rut,
        c.Razon,
        o.OrdenID,
        o.Oc,
        o.CDestino,
        o.NDestino,
        o.FEntrega,
        o.CProveedor,
        o.CCencosud,
        o.Descripcion,
        o.CBulto,
        Correlativo = o.SBulto ? s.Correlativo : o.Correlativo,
        EPedido = o.SBulto ? s.Unidad : o.EPedido
    }
    into x
    group x by x.Correlativo into y
    select new
    {
        OrdenID = y.Select(d => d.OrdenID).FirstOrDefault(),
        Rut = y.Select(d => d.Rut).FirstOrDefault(),
        Razon = y.Select(d => d.Razon).FirstOrDefault(),
        Oc = y.Select(d => d.Oc).FirstOrDefault(),
        CDestino = y.Select(d => d.CDestino).FirstOrDefault(),
        NDestino = y.Select(d => d.NDestino).FirstOrDefault(),
        FEntrega = y.Select(d => d.FEntrega).FirstOrDefault(),
        CProveedor = y.Select(d => d.CProveedor).FirstOrDefault(),
        CCencosud = y.Select(d => d.CCencosud).FirstOrDefault(),
        Descripcion = y.Select(d => d.Descripcion).FirstOrDefault(),
        CBulto = y.Select(d => d.CBulto).FirstOrDefault(),
        Correlativo = y.Key,
        EPedido = y.Select(d => d.EPedido).Sum(),
    }
```

sintaxis de método de LINQ ?

```
    TableBulto = db.Clientes.Include(o => o.Ordens)
```

La sintaxis de consulta y la sintaxis de método son idénticas desde el punto de vista semántico, pero muchos usuarios creen que la sintaxis de consulta es mucho más sencilla y fácil de leer.

Comment: Que??!!!! No se te entiende, ni el problema, ni lo que buscas ni lo que estas haciendo

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Hola, esta consulta funciona bien y esta escrita utilizando sintaxis de consulta declarativa de LINQ. Lo que intento es reescribirla utilizando sintaxIs de método de LINQ. [Referencia](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/query-syntax-and-method-syntax-in-linq)

Comment: Ahora entiendo tu pregunta, lo que pasa es que habitualmente lo que tu llamas "sintaxis de método" se conoce como `Expresiones Lambda` o en otros lenguajes como `Arrow Functions`, pero creo que "sintaxis de método" no estaría mal tampoco. El tema es que porque quieres cambiar la sintaxis?? Al ver tu respuesta de abajo me parece que la sintaxis original es mucho más limpia

Comment: [Guia de aprendizaje para conceptos utilizados](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/query-syntax-and-method-syntax-in-linq#standard-query-operator-extension-methods)  Por que estaba experimentando. Coincido en que la consulta original es mucho mas limpia.

Comment: Sintaxis de método (Method syntax) es la terminología correcta: https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/linq/write-linq-queries#example---method-syntax

Answer (score 0):

Mi consulta reescrita utilizando syntaxis de método de LINQ.

Información para reescritura obtenida en :

https://dotnettutorials.net/lesson/left-outer-join-in-linq/

Agradecere su comentario o consejos, gracias.

```
                var TableBulto = db.Clientes
                .Join(db.Ordens, cl => cl.ClienteID, occl => occl.ClienteID, (cl, occl) => new { cl, occl })
                .GroupJoin(db.SBultos, oc => oc.occl.OrdenID, sb => sb.OrdenID, (oc, sb) => new { oc, sb })
                .Where(w => w.oc.occl.Oc == ValorOrden && w.oc.occl.Carga == ValorCarga && w.oc.occl.ClienteID == ValorIdCliente && w.oc.occl.CPallet == 0)
                .SelectMany(x => x.sb.DefaultIfEmpty(), (oc, sb) => new { oc, sb })
                .Select(s => new
                {
                    s.oc.oc.cl.Rut,
                    s.oc.oc.cl.Razon,
                    s.oc.oc.occl.OrdenID,
                    s.oc.oc.occl.Oc,
                    s.oc.oc.occl.CDestino,
                    s.oc.oc.occl.NDestino,
                    s.oc.oc.occl.FEntrega,
                    s.oc.oc.occl.CProveedor,
                    s.oc.oc.occl.CCencosud,
                    s.oc.oc.occl.Descripcion,
                    s.oc.oc.occl.CBulto,
                    Corre = s.oc.oc.occl.SBulto ? s.sb.Correlativo : s.oc.oc.occl.Correlativo,
                    EPedido = s.oc.oc.occl.SBulto ? s.sb.Unidad : s.oc.oc.occl.EPedido
                })
                .GroupBy(g => g.Corre)
                .Select(y => new
                {
                    OrdenID = y.Select(d => d.OrdenID).FirstOrDefault(),
                    Rut = y.Select(d => d.Rut).FirstOrDefault(),
                    Razon = y.Select(d => d.Razon).FirstOrDefault(),
                    Oc = y.Select(d => d.Oc).FirstOrDefault(),
                    CDestino = y.Select(d => d.CDestino).FirstOrDefault(),
                    NDestino = y.Select(d => d.NDestino).FirstOrDefault(),
                    FEntrega = y.Select(d => d.FEntrega).FirstOrDefault(),
                    CProveedor = y.Select(d => d.CProveedor).FirstOrDefault(),
                    CCencosud = y.Select(d => d.CCencosud).FirstOrDefault(),
                    Descripcion = y.Select(d => d.Descripcion).FirstOrDefault(),
                    CBulto = y.Select(d => d.CBulto).FirstOrDefault(),
                    Correlativo = y.Key,
                    EPedido = y.Select(d => d.EPedido).Sum(),
                })
                .ToList()
```